# Reuse of a node in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

For a project that I am working on, I am making a tikz picture and need to have the same node multiple times. Is there a way (such as \tikzset or other) that I can define a node once and then reprint/reuse it somewhere else?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[rectangle, draw] (node1) {InsertComplexNodeHere};
\node[rectangle, draw] (node2) [below of=node1] {ExactSameAsAbove};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit for better information**:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[rectangle, draw] (node1) {\includegraphics{image.png}};
\node[rectangle, draw] (node2) [below of=node1] {\includegraphics{image.png}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I need this image multiple times in different locations, but might have to make changes to the image reference/name/size/etc, and would prefer to define it once and then do something like:

```
\node[copy of node1] (node3) at (3,3)
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide more context. You can 1) define a custom style using `\tikzset{mystyle/.style={rectangle, draw}}` and then `\node[mystyle] ...`, but you can 2) also define a custom command such as `\newcommand\mynode{\node[rectangle, draw] (node1) {InsertComplexNodeHere};}` (but note that it might not be the best idea to define two nodes with the exact same name as this can lead to confusion). There may be even more ways such as `\pic`s. It highly depends on what you exactly want to do.

Comment: Yes @campa. I am using tikzset to define certain styles that I am repeating, but I'm trying to reuse the typeset material in each. For example, I need to place a certain picture in multiple locations, and instead of having do `\includegraphics ...` multiple times, defining it once and then referring to it again so it shows up identically in a different location.

Comment: Just use  `\savebox` for the content and reuse that in the nodes.

Comment: Look for \pic{}.

Comment: @MS-SPO , using the \pic seems to be closer to what I need, but I cannot seem to find a way to refer to it later. So when I need to put a node to the right of a picture, I cannot refer to it.

Comment: \pic (a) at (0,1) {yourcontent}; \pic (b) at (3,4){yourcontent}; \draw (a) — (b); etc. what else do you need? Whatever you put as yourcontent (node ensembles, wild curves etc.) is replicated. Think more of a macro and less as an object you may know from OOP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like a use-case for `node contents`.  This is a key that does what it says on the tin: it specifies the *contents* of the node.  It's an alternative to `\node {contents};` meaning that the contents can be set by a TikZ style, giving greater flexibility.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/699407/86}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{
  positioning,
  shapes.geometric
}

\tikzset{
  my complicated node/.style={
    node contents={Some complicated text},
    draw,
    ellipse,
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[my complicated node,name=node1];
\node[my complicated node,below=of node1];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Two identical nodes, one below the other]

Answer (score 2):

Using @Alan Munn's advice (I had never heard of saveboxes until now), I was able to solve the issue. Thank you!

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\newsavebox\Reuseblock
\sbox\Reuseblock{\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (ru) {\includegraphics{image.png}};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[rectangle, draw] (node1) {\usebox\Reuseblock};
\node[rectangle, draw] (node2) [below of=node1] {\\usebox\Reuseblock};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't nest `tikzpictures`. Why don't you just put the `\includegraphics` in a macro and use that?

Comment: Yes, indeed. My suggestion was to use the `\savebox` for the content only.

Comment: I believe putting `\includegraphics` inside a savebox is faster, especially for JPEGs which involve 2D Fourier transforms.  Putting the entire tikzpicture just adds `inner sep` as a border.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more Tikz-ish solution.

The first page uses a simple self-defined pic-style called `img`, and places as many of these as you want:

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}[% self-defined styles to be used here
    img/.pic={% now just draw what shall be inside img
        \node {\includegraphics{example-image-duck}};   
    }
 ]
    % ~~~ placing two nodes containing the image ~~~
    \pic at (0,0)   {img}; % read: a pic at (0,0) with style img
    \pic at (8,4)   {img};
    \pic at (15,-7) {img};
 \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: result]

The second example passes just 1 parameter. Kindly see the different "call", better specification, of the style to be used:

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    pics/img2/.style args={#1}{% allow one parameter to be passed
        code={
            \node (A)  {\includegraphics{example-image-duck}};
            \node [below=of A,yshift=5mm] {#1};
        }
    }
 ]
    % ~~~ placing two nodes containing the image ~~~
    \pic at ( 0,-3)     {img2={A duck!}};
    \pic at (15,-4)     {img2={May be duck}};
    \pic at ( 8, 7)     {img2={No duck}};
 \end{tikzpicture}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}%  when you want to use images, incl. the duck
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}


\begin{document}
 % ~~~ 1st example ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 \begin{tikzpicture}[% self-defined styles to be used here
    img/.pic={% now just draw what shall be inside img
        \node {\includegraphics{example-image-duck}};   
    }
 ]
    % ~~~ placing two nodes containing the image ~~~
    \pic at (0,0)   {img}; % read: a pic at (0,0) with style img
    \pic at (8,4)   {img};
    \pic at (15,-7) {img};
 \end{tikzpicture}

 % ~~~ 2nd example ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    pics/img2/.style args={#1}{% allow one parameter to be passed
        code={
            \node (A)  {\includegraphics{example-image-duck}};
            \node [below=of A,yshift=5mm] {#1};
        }
    }
 ]
    % ~~~ placing two nodes containing the image ~~~
    \pic at ( 0,-3)     {img2={A duck!}};
    \pic at (15,-4)     {img2={May be duck}};
    \pic at ( 8, 7)     {img2={No duck}};
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```